# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk, build.gradle

I developing application for human detection using NDK and OpenCV.

Getting error like this.
**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/android/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd''**

Computer OS : Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit).

Android studio version is: 3.0.1

Could you please help me.Last 2 days on-words i'm trying resolve this error.I have searched in google,but that solutions are not resolved this error.

I have tried like this:

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
Mat mRgba,igray,iCanny;
BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallaBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS: {
                javaCameraView.enableView();
                break;

            }
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }
        super.onManagerConnected(status);
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    javaCameraView =(JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(javaCameraView!=null)
        javaCameraView.disableView();
}
protected void onDistroy(){
    super.onPause();
    if(javaCameraView!=null)
        javaCameraView.disableView();
}

protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d(TAG,"SUCESSES");
            mLoaderCallaBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);

        }else {
            Log.d(TAG,"FAIL");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9,this,mLoaderCallaBack);
        }

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    igray = new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}
@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
}
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    //NativeClass.faceDetection(mRgba.getNotificationObjAdde());
    //Imgproc.ctv

    return mRgba;
   }
 }
```

> build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.opencv"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine '/home/android/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd',
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }

buildTypes{
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation project(':openCVLibrary249')
  }
```

> ```
>  Android.mk
> ```

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_test_opencv_NativeClass.cpp
  LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
  LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibs
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

> Application.mk

```
 APP_STL := gnustl_static
 APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
 APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
 APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

> ```
> com_test_opencv_NativeClass.cpp:
> ```

```
  #include <com_test_opencv_NativeClass.h>
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL    Java_com_test_opencv_NativeClass_humenDetection
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass,obj){
      return env->NewStringUTF("This is from JNI");
   }
```

> com_test_opencv_NativeClass.h

```
 /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
 /* Header for class com_test_opencv_NativeClass */

 #ifndef _Included_com_test_opencv_NativeClass
 #define _Included_com_test_opencv_NativeClass
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_opencv_NativeClass_faceDetection
 (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_opencv_NativeClass_humenDetection
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  #endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **build.gradle** uses an old template, not relevant for Android Studio 3, and also, you have probably merged two sources, which contradict one another.

The immediate problem, though, is that your **ndkBuild** is built for Windows, and if you simply remove `.cmd`, your script may work on Ubuntu. But let us clean it up a bit:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.opencv"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
  }

  externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
      path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary249')
  }
}
```

This assumes that `:openCVLibrary249` is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply .After changing the build.prob getting this error: unknown type name 'obj'
Error:(5, 1) error: void function 'Java_com_test_opencv_NativeClass_humenDetection' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
Error:(4, 22) error: unknown type name 'obj'
Error:(5, 1) error: void function 'Java_com_test_opencv_NativeClass_humenDetection' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: Yes, the file `com_test_opencv_NativeClass.cpp` is corrupted. Change `jclass,obj` to `jcalss, jlong`.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.I am new to NDK and open CV.I'm learning NDK from you tube videos. Again i got another error is ..Befor adding .mk files its working condition is going to success.Now its going to fail condition...I have added MainActivity.java in the question.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.test.opencv/com.test.opencv.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
                                                                      at com.test.opencv.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:76)